# Centos 7 / FreePBX14 Distro Email

Tags: centos, email, freepbx

I am trying to find out what mail service is being used to send voicemail to email on Centos 7 / FreePBX14 Distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of Google compelled me to find [the blog](https://www.freepbx.org/freepbx-14-distro-14-more-blog/) for version 14, which led me to [FreePDX Project](https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP) and thence to [Checking the Email Queue](https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/PPS/Checking+Email+Queue) which showed it's [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).

Comment: PS: Since you're new, if this answer was useful and productive, please click on the grey arrowhead at left. If it was also the best answer, please click on the check mark below it, which lets others know which answer's best.